# Console does not show 4 bytes utf-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, console

I'm using Ubuntu. My console (using Python or bash) does not print utf8 chars of 4 bytes, only 3 bytes or less.

Example (bash):

```
eran@eran-MS-7788:~/Dropbox/help$ echo -e "\xee\x8c\xb0"
# This prints the v sign
eran@eran-MS-7788:~/Dropbox/help$ echo -e "\xf0\x9f\x8f\x80"
# This should print the basketball sign but does not print so
```

I get the same from the Python console.

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most so called Unicode fonts only implement characters present in Unicode BMP (Basic Multiligual Plane) - from `U+0000` to `U+FFFF`, which all can be represented using just 3 bytes using `UTF-8`.

There are very few fonts that implement characters beyond BMP: that is, from `U+010000` to `U+1FFFFF` (which are encoded using 4 bytes in `UTF-8`), and I would think that your Linux console or terminal is no exception. Because of this, you are not likely to see character you expect. Over time, it is possible that support for characters beyond BMP would become better, but it will probably take a long time. You can read more about this [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_unicode_fonts.html).